# Building openaplr using visual studio 2013

Tags: opencv

I am trying to build OpenALPR om Visual studio 2013 and i get the following errors on the `MotionDetector.cpp` and `Platelines.cpp`

> Error 273 error C2039: '()' : is not a member of
>   'cv::BackgroundSubtractor'
>
> Error 189 error C2039: 'adaptiveBilateralFilter' : is not a member of
>   'cv'

i think the problem is in these two lines for the motion detector
for the platelines.cpp

```
pMOG2 = cv::BackgroundSubtractorMOG2();

pMOG2->operator()(*frame, fgMaskMOG2, 1);

adaptiveBilateralFilter(inputImage, smoothed, Size(3,3), 45, 45);
```

this is the line which has the error

Comment: which opencv version are you using ? (it seems, that OpenALPR expects something outdated)

Comment: Have you checked if you are using the right version of opencv? (as in if these functions exist)

Comment: am using opencv 3.0 beta

Comment: yeah these functions do exist, thats the lkatest opencv besides the new stable virsion

Comment: i dont think am using the functions right

Comment: pMOG2 = cv::BackgroundSubtractorMOG2();
}

MotionDetector::~MotionDetector()
{

}

void MotionDetector::ResetMotionDetection(cv::Mat* frame)
{
 pMOG2->operator()(*frame, fgMaskMOG2, 1);
}

cv::Rect MotionDetector::MotionDetect(cv::Mat* frame)
//Detect motion and create ONE recangle that contains all the detected motion
{
 std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;
 std::vector<cv::Vec4i> hierarchy;
 cv::Rect bounding_rect;
 std::vector<cv::Rect> rects;
 cv::Rect largest_rect, rect_temp;

 // Detect motion
 pMOG2->operator()(*frame, fgMaskMOG2, -1);

Comment: Unreadable. Put it in your question.

Comment: adaptiveBilateralFilter got removed, and you have to [change the BackgroundSubtractor](http://docs.opencv.org/ref/master/db/d73/background__segm_8hpp.html) code

Comment: what did they replace it with?

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/ref/master/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#ga9d7064d478c95d60003cf839430737ed

Comment: i also just fixed the background subtractor problem now i have what seems like a trivial problem but i dont know how to solve it:  Error 106 error C2099: initializer is not a constant 
 OnigEncoding OnigEncDefaultCharEncoding = ONIG_ENCODING_INIT_DEFAULT;